# I have 29 textboxes and 29 labels and lots of (IF)'s

Tags: vb.net

i have 29 textBoxes and 29 labels 
how can i make it easier instead of writning all 29's every time
and there is 29 (IF)

```
        Label1.ForeColor = c2
        Label2.ForeColor = c1
        Label3.ForeColor = c2
```

' There is lot of texts and labels and (IF) condition

Comment: Look into the `For Each` loop construct.

Comment: `vb.net` and `vba` are entirely different technologies.  Please tag your question correctly.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those cases usually there are some controls that you need to change and other that need to be static. If that is the case you can use a List(T) to store the elements you want to change and then as @FreeMan stated use a For Each loop

For your case the code would be something similar to this(please note this is an idea and you may need to tweak it):

```
Dim lblList as New List(Of Label)({Label1, Label2, Label3})
'Then you loop the List to assign the values. Even can include if statements 
For Each lbl As Label In lblList
    lbl.ForeColor = c1
Next
```

Please give it a try and let me know your comments

Comment: Error BC30638 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.

Comment: thanx a lot thats good so far and think i'm getting to make it work but its when i press anykey on my keyboard some label has to change the color like "Q" ,"E" etc...

Comment: Yes It WORKED thanx man i just had to make it in every (IF) statement and you saved me like 500 lines thanx again

Comment: ok how i can do that with boolean like (g1,g2,g3,....g29)  is there a way

Comment: example: , if key "S" down g1=false , g2=false ,,, g19= true but in a smother way   thanx a lot